# How to remove the greyed out look of a UIButton when hovering over

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, 3dtouch

In my iPhone app, I have a bunch of `UIButton` which I have created in the `Interface Builder`. Each button has a `GestureRecognizer` to recognise hard pressure (3D touch) and when enough force is applied, I change the UIButton Image and do some calculation as well.

This all works fine, the only problem is that each button goes into a greyed out look when they are lightly touched (hovered over).

How do I get rid of this behavior?

Below is parts of my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!
    ...

        let btnDeepPressGestureRecognizer = DeepPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.btnDeepPressHandler(_:)), threshold: self.deepPressureThreshold)
        btn.addGestureRecognizer(btnDeepPressGestureRecognizer)

    ...
    func btnDeepPressHandler(_ value: DeepPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if value.state == .began {
            ...
        } else if value.state == .ended {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Screen shot of one of the buttons attribute inspector:

[image]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your attribute inspector in storyboard for one of your buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only think of two things right now:

you can try this:

```
yourButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
```

and this:

```
yourButton.adjustsImageWhenDisabled = false
```

According to documentation:

> When the Shows Touch On Highlight (showsTouchWhenHighlighted) option
>   is enabled, the button adds a white glow to the part of a button that
>   the user touches.
>
> When the Highlighted Adjusts Image (adjustsImageWhenHighlighted)
>   option is enabled, button images get darker when it is in the
>   highlighted state.
>
> When the Disabled Adjusts Image (adjustsImageWhenDisabled) option is
>   enabled, the image is dimmed when the button is disabled.

Since it happens on light touch, your button should be highlighted and glow but it's dimmed so maybe it's somehow disabled.

Comment: btn.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false, solves the issue.